# I want to implement remote validation for registration but not login in ASP.NET, as it won't let any user login

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, model-view-controller, razor

I know that this would be easier if I had different view models for login and register however unfortunately they must be in the same view model.
This is the relevant methods in usercontroller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([Bind("Email,Password")]UserViewModel m)
        {        
            // call service to Authenticate User
            var user = svc.Authenticate(m.Email, m.Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Invalid Login Credentials");
                ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Invalid Login Credentials");
                return View(m);
            }
           
            // sign user in using cookie authentication to store principal
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                BuildClaimsPrincipal(user)
            );
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }

        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        // add validate anti forgery token
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Register([Bind("Name, Email, Password, PasswordConfirm, Role")]UserViewModel m)
        {
            // Q2

            // attempt to retrieve a user by the viewmodel email address (call svc.GetUserByEmail(m.Email))
            // var user = svc.GetUserByEmail(m.Email);
            // // if user returned is not null then 
            // if(user != null)
            // //    add a modelstate error as email address must already be in use   
            // //  see login action above for example of adding manual modelstate error  
            //    {
            //        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email Address Already In Use");
            //        return View(m);
            //    }   
            // endif 
            // if not valid model
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              return View(m);
            }                
            // call service to register user
            // Add alert indicating registration successful and redirect to login page
            svc.Register(m.Name, m.Email, m.Password, m.Role);
            Alert("Registration Successful", AlertType.info);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }
[AcceptVerbs("GET","POST")]
        public IActionResult VerifyEmail(string email)
        {
          if (svc.GetUserByEmail(email) != null)
          {
            return Json($"Email {email} is already in use.");
          }

          return Json(true);
        }
```

This is the userviewmodel

```
public class UserViewModel
    {  
        // Q3 add validation attributes
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Remote(action: "VerifyEmail", controller: "User")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password doesn't match! Try again!")]
        public string PasswordConfirm  { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        

    }
```

So when I register, if the email is in use it shows an error which is great! But, on the login page it says email already in use and will not allow login for anyone?
Has anyone a solution whilst keeping the model the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Request** object **Referer** header. Add these lines at the start of your **VerifyEmail** method:

```
var referer = Request.Headers["Referer"];

if (referer.Count > 0 && referer.ToString().Contains("Login"))
{
   return Json(true);
}
```

We're checking the incoming request origin page in the header and if it's present and is initiated from the login page we are not proceeding further.